# Trouble With Conditionally Showing FIelds on Dynamic HTML Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655032/how-to-automatically-bind-multiple-event-handlers-with-a-loop-in-jquery) clarified using classes for this. However the answer below is more accurate.

I have a html form which grows to an undefined number of inputs groups. Each input is assigned an incrementing ID. I'm trying to show fields in each group based on the select input. So far it works fine for the first field group with the ID = 0.

So the initial form looks like this in html:

```
<ol id="activity">
  <li class="activity_var">
    <select name="activity-type_0" id="activity-type_0">
      <option>Choose Activity</option>
      <option value="Drilling">Drilling</option>
      <option value="Casing">Casing</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="activity-drill_0" id="activity-drill_0"/>
    <button type="button" class="activity_del">Delete Button</button>
  </li>
</ol>
<input type="button" value="Add Button" class="activity_add">
```

However as the form grows I'm struggling on how to target each new group based on the new ID.

For example as the form grows by 1 additional field group it increments all the ID's by 1 like so:

```
<ol id="activity">

  <li class="activity_var">
    <select name="activity-type_0" id="activity-type_0">
      <option>Choose Activity</option>
      <option value="Drilling">Drilling</option>
      <option value="Casing">Casing</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="" name="activity-drill_0" id="activity-drill_0">
    <button type="button" class="activity_del" style="">Delete Button</button>
  </li>

<li class="activity_var">
    <select name="activity-type_1" id="activity-type_1">
      <option>Choose Activity</option>
      <option value="Drilling">Drilling</option>
      <option value="Casing">Casing</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="activity-drill_1" id="activity-drill_1">
    <button type="button" class="activity_del" style="">Delete Button</button>
  </li>

</ol>
```

I'm using the following jQuery function to conditionally show the fields in group 1 with ID = 0. This works fine.

```
//Show or hide based on select
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#activity-type_0').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Drilling"){
    $("#activity-drill_0").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#activity-drill_0").hide()
    }
});
});
```

But how can I dynamically use the above function to target the new field groups and their new ID's?

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery but I imagine some sort of count and loop is needed?

Comment: Basically you need to show and hide based on dynamic id(which is in sequence) ?

Comment: I would not use IDs; use CSS classes to target each drop down and its sibling text box. See [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector) for more info.

Comment: @Duck_dragon Yes exactly but we don't know the exact length of the sequence it could be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would add a css class or data-attribute to all select tags that describe your activities like so:

```
<select name="activity-type_0" class="activity-types">
```

So you can listen on all elements with one call:

```
$('.activity-types').on('change', function(e) { ... }
```

Next I would add data-attributes with the same value as the option value to the fields you want to show/hide:

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" name="activity-drill_0" id="activity-drill_0" data-activity="Drilling">
<input type="text" style="display: none" name="activity-casing_0" id="activity-casing_0" data-activity="Casing">
```

With that you can check which select field changed and show the siblings form field based on the option you have chosen:

```
$('.activity-types').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#' + e.target.id).siblings('[data-activity=' + $(e.target).val() + ']').show();
}
```

Comment: The answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655032/how-to-automatically-bind-multiple-event-handlers-with-a-loop-in-jquery) clarified using classes for this. However yours works exactly as I need for this question Thank You!